# Why say A times X is a combination of the columns of A?

Tags: linear-algebra

How to understand

When I watching this [tutorial of linear algebra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZK3O402wf1c&list=PL49CF3715CB9EF31D&index=1), at `38:40` moment,

Gilbert Strang say:

> A times X is a combination of the columns of A.

I don't understand this sentence,
in my option, A is combination of each column of A, why there say A times X is a combination of the columns of A?

Comment: Do you know what a linear combination is? Do you know why matrix multiplication is even defined the way it is? The main utility of matrices is that they encode linear combinations (of bases) in a nice way. Test it for yourself; write down a $3\times3$ matrix and a vector in $\Bbb R^3$, do the multiplication and notice that the result is the same as if you had multiplied the first column of $A$ by the first entry in the vector, added it to the second column of $A$ multiplied by the second entry in the vector, and added it to the third column multiplied by the third entry: a linear combination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is meant is

$AX = a_1x_1 + \ldots+ a_nx_n$,

where $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ denote the columns of $A$ and $X$ is the column vector $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)^T$.

Comment: the `a_1, ...., a_n `'s `a` is the `a combination of the columns of A`'s `a` in this sentence, right?

Answer (score 1):

Just calculate

$\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & 2 & 3  \\
   4 & 5 & 6  \\
   7 & 8 & 9  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\left( \begin{matrix}
   x  \\
   y  \\
   z  \\
\end{matrix} \right)=\left( \begin{matrix}
   x+2y+3z  \\
   4x+5y+6z  \\
   7x+8y+9z  \\
\end{matrix} \right)=x\left( \begin{matrix}
   1  \\
   4  \\
   7  \\
\end{matrix} \right)+y\left( \begin{matrix}
   2  \\
   5  \\
   8  \\
\end{matrix} \right)+z\left( \begin{matrix}
   3  \\
   6  \\
   9  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$

It gives an interesting viewpoint; the solution of $Ax=b$ is now "can b be a linear combination of the columns of A?" or "Is b in the span of the columns of A?".  If b is not in this subspace, what is the closest point in the subspace to b, is then a natural question (the least squares solution of $Ax=b$).